# Error Connecting to Online redis Database

Tags: node.js, next.js, redis

I am trying to connect to my online redis database.

```
const redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient({
  password: '<password>',
  socket: {
      host: <host>
      port: <port>
  }
});

client.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('client connected');
});

client.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error('Error connecting to server: ', err); 
});

client.set('mykey', 'myvalue', function(err, result) { 
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error setting value - : ', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Value set - ', result);
  }
});
```

However, when attempting to execute the code, an error of "Unhandled Runtime Error: Error: The client is closed" arises. I have observed that some individuals have recommended invoking the "Connect" method on the client; nonetheless, this results in the error message "client.connect" or "net.connect" is not a function. I am seeking guidance on how to address this issue.

For the purpose of connecting to my Redis database, I have installed the following dependencies using the npm package manager: redis, ioredis, redis-om, and node-redis.

I have also replaced the values , , and  with the values given to me by redis.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Node Redis 3.x way of doing things. Node Redis 4.x uses Promises instead of callback. Here's the [connect example](https://github.com/redis/node-redis#basic-example) from the top of the [README](https://github.com/redis/node-redis) that shows you the preferred way of doing this:

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient();

client.on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

await client.connect();

await client.set('key', 'value');
const value = await client.get('key');
await client.disconnect();
```

Note that you should only need the `redis` package for what you are trying to do. It is also the official Node.js client from Redis. I wrote `redis-om`, which uses the `redis` package, and while I'd be delighted if you used it, it's not needed for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this error before. Then I installed `ioredis` package. Now it works well. Here's my solution:

```js
import Redis from "ioredis";

const client = new Redis({
  host: <host>,
  port: <port>,
  password: <password>,
});
```